# Juju 2.0 proxy for bootstrap

Tags: juju, proxy

Although `juju model-config` supports proxies, before a model exists, I'm having a very hard time setting an HTTP proxy.

Just running `juju bootstrap localhost lxd-test` fails because juju doesn't use the proxy.

How can I tell Juju to use a proxy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the MAAS freenode community, I learned that I could run:

`--config=config.yaml`

Where config.yaml contains:

```
default-series: xenial
no-proxy: localhost
apt-http-proxy: http://<ip address>:<port>
apt-https-proxy: https://<ip address>:<port>
apt-ftp-proxy: ftp://<ip address>:<port>
http-proxy: http://<ip address>:<port>
https-proxy: https://<ip address>:<port>
ftp-proxy: ftp://<ip address>:<port>
```

This isn't documented anywhere in the MAAS or Juju documentation, disappointingly. This didn't actually solve my issue either, though I believe it addressed the direct question of setting a proxy before a model exists. I believe the issue I'm having is due to unrelated DNS confusion within my network.

Comment: I found this comment by ptylenda [here](https://github.com/conjure-up/conjure-up/issues/171) which might be useful although it looks like the issue was closed and the PPA was updated.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure exactly what changes were made, but it doesn't appear that anything like the old `environments.yaml` has come back.

Comment: @NateGardner It is documented right [here](https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/models-config). I'm curious whether you used the doc site. If you did, did a search for 'proxy' not work out?

Comment: I didn't see the line "These values can also be passed to a new controller for use with the default model it creates. To do this, use the --config argument with bootstrap." It appeared this could only be set after a model was created based on the intro to the section.

Comment: Additionally I had to add "snap-http-proxy: http://<ip address>:<port>" and "snap-https-proxy: https://<ip address>:<port>"

Answer (score 2):

Use

`--config http-proxy=http://<ip address>:<port>
--config https-proxy=http://<ip address>:<port>`

Answer (score 2):

During the bootstrap process, you probably want to specify the proxies as model defaults. These will apply both to the controller model, and to any subsequent models that are created in that controller.

```
juju bootstrap lxd --model-defaults=config.yaml
```

Configuration attributes specified with --config will only apply to the controller model, and not other models.

Comment: `Error: flag provided but not defined: --model-defaults.`

This isn't valid syntax in the current version of Juju