# DNS Confusion: curl and wget got through but host and dig do not

Tags: networking, server, juju, dns, maas

For every Linux machine running I have used on my corporate intranet, I am able to use the corporate DNS and corporate proxy without any trouble for most high-level functions such as `wget`, `curl`, using a web browser, and even running MAAS.

However, when I try something like `host google.com`, I get the response `Host google.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN).`

When I try `dig google.com` I get `;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1`
. Under the `AUTHORITY SECTION`, the correct DNS server is listed.

Using `strace` and `tcpdump` I have confirmed that both `wget` and `curl` are using the same DNS server as `dig` and `host`.

This has become a problem for me recently as I'm trying to deploy Juju. `juju bootstrap` is among `dig` and `host` in its inability to get through my corporate DNS. Running `juju bootstrap localhost lxd-test` results in:

`ERROR failed to bootstrap model: cannot start bootstrap instance: unable to get LXD image for ubuntu-xenial: Get https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases//streams/v1/index.json: lookup cloud-images.ubuntu.com on <my DNS IPs> no such host`.

Of course, I'm also using a `--connfig=config.yaml` where `config.yaml` [contains all of the appropriate proxy information](https://askubuntu.com/a/852871/573381).

I need a solution that will enable Juju to get to `cloud-images.ubuntu.com`.

The `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environment variables are set. `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` are not.

I found that the IP address of `cloud-images.ubuntu.com` is `91.189.88.141`. I tried `host 91.189.88.141` and got:
`Host 141.88.189.91.in-addr.arpa. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)`

My `/etc/resolv.conf` contains the correct DNS server IP addresses.

Any ideas on how to get my DNS settings fully functioning, especially for the purposes of getting Juju through my DNS?