# Juju bootstrap of LXD fails behind a proxy

Tags: juju, proxy, lxc

I'm trying to bootstrap juju on a virtualbox machine with ubuntu 16.04 using lxd cloud obtainig the error

```
ERROR Get https://10.229.0.1:8443/1.0: Gateway Time-out
```

Snap says:

```
sysop@ubuntu01:~$ sudo snap list
[sudo] password for sysop: 
Name  Version  Rev   Developer  Notes
core  16-2     1689  canonical  -
juju  2.2.0    1956  canonical  classic
lxd   2.14     2417  canonical  -
```

LXC is working correctly and I have a container delivered. lxc list says:

```
sysop@ubuntu01:~$ lxc list --verbose
+-------+---------+--------------------+------+------------+-----------+
| NAME  |  STATE  |        IPV4        | IPV6 |    TYPE    | SNAPSHOTS |
+-------+---------+--------------------+------+------------+-----------+
| primo | RUNNING | 10.229.0.73 (eth0) |      | PERSISTENT | 0         |
+-------+---------+--------------------+------+------------+-----------+
```

I'm behind a proxy that requires authentication so in lxc info I have:

```
sysop@ubuntu01:~$ lxc info
config:
   core.https_address: '[::]'
   core.proxy_http: http://user:password@proxy-address:8080/
   core.proxy_https: http://user:password@proxy-address:8080/
   core.proxy_ignore_hosts: localhost
```

The output of juju bootstrap is:

```
    sysop@ubuntu01:~$ juju bootstrap localhost lxd1 --debug
    09:34:53 INFO  juju.cmd supercommand.go:63 running juju [2.2.0 gc go1.8]
    09:34:53 DEBUG juju.cmd supercommand.go:64   args: []string{"/snap/juju/1956/bin/juju", "bootstrap", "localhost", "lxd1", "--debug"}
    09:34:53 DEBUG juju.tools.lxdclient client.go:230 connecting to LXD remote "local": "unix:///var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/unix.socket"
    09:34:54 INFO  juju.tools.lxdclient client.go:284 using LXD API version "1.0"
    09:34:54 INFO  juju.tools.lxdclient client.go:333 LXD "default" profile uses network bridge "lxdbr0"
    09:34:54 INFO  cmd provider.go:179 Resolved LXD host address on bridge lxdbr0: 10.229.0.1:8443
    09:34:54 INFO  cmd cloudcredential.go:51 no credentials found, checking environment
    09:34:54 DEBUG juju.tools.lxdclient client.go:230 connecting to LXD remote "local": "unix:///var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/unix.socket"
    09:34:54 INFO  juju.tools.lxdclient client.go:284 using LXD API version "1.0"
    09:34:54 INFO  juju.tools.lxdclient client.go:333 LXD "default" profile uses network bridge "lxdbr0"
    09:34:54 DEBUG juju.cmd.juju.commands bootstrap.go:803 authenticating with region "" and credential "localhost" (LXD credential "localhost")
    09:34:54 DEBUG juju.cmd.juju.commands bootstrap.go:915 provider attrs: map[]
    09:34:54 INFO  cmd authkeys.go:114 Adding contents of "/home/sysop/.local/share/juju/ssh/juju_id_rsa.pub" to authorized-keys
    09:34:54 INFO  cmd authkeys.go:114 Adding contents of "/home/sysop/.ssh/id_rsa.pub" to authorized-keys
    09:34:54 DEBUG juju.cmd.juju.commands bootstrap.go:971 preparing controller with config: map[net-bond-reconfigure-delay:17 disable-network-management:false authorized-keys:ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCpLnUIrvGmeOMKaH0KLltB94Hn20c4ARM6/vSW6PguUr04+EzU2q9s/GFiIq7VjC0aWxQydDJG/4HqThf0VX5nB9h5sYBLIaq8LoMemw/FtsZrnQ2En3u9kngvcYkRmQEcyCzdHmhzVKG1JAE3NYz67aCaa2OAWZw7fDcXP78KsYDuSv8eTFr4qPoGGi2ayG/NeXkM8WgS8fgQI9emOn9zFVrHIo7Ah2Wa9ucUJjXQvNA+6hZjM2DnxeLV4gdVLxLBvxF1Vj9MHqArPBUZ4ZEFGcdXYoPyny2S6iT3vf3fbCaU785JNweCQwZ0oxRXCDYWXPhGY4zVwzUK1ykojOrh juju-client-key
    ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCjq011k7jLFei5RL7m07dDwEHA4hoKI9AN/WlfjH+ThrUErSV4vG3SRL3jClUldirTTLeT3XwwiGMpLAfxtamI/cbFjuqCY7nHJ+zgQ+GfmgpMfulYxJgz9D1oGdL8+Mn3EfG5V4pfDe1uTiOkmKkChh53rWTznAuDQYbFaXlbQdsVbUDRjmhuAjKnPqX/81WKeB4XedNAsycsqhBmK2ITx22ff2PwkHaegsGUzbXcRVY8i47gq96vCU3gLb64fUkTA9miEAovtpalsr13jSbzTrLfwtExVbpew0EAb4de5BqQATqOtexD6CNzkxEzmHp7am0c8MdzMjBFpkCIN29/ sysop@ubuntu01
    automatically-retry-hooks:true agent-metadata-url: type:lxd ignore-machine-addresses:false proxy-ssh:false image-stream:released enable-os-upgrade:true apt-ftp-proxy: ftp-proxy: http-proxy: transmit-vendor-metrics:true name:controller apt-https-proxy: firewall-mode:instance logforward-enabled:false default-series:xenial max-status-history-age:336h ssl-hostname-verification:true no-proxy:127.0.0.1,localhost,::1 apt-mirror: https-proxy: max-status-history-size:5G apt-no-proxy: resource-tags: apt-http-proxy: logging-config: agent-stream:released uuid:2168b6e8-f8b8-4edb-8982-191e4b407901 test-mode:false provisioner-harvest-mode:destroyed image-metadata-url: development:false enable-os-refresh-update:true]
    09:34:54 DEBUG juju.tools.lxdclient client.go:230 connecting to LXD remote "remote": "10.229.0.1:8443"
    ERROR Get https://10.229.0.1:8443/1.0: Gateway Time-out
    09:34:54 DEBUG cmd supercommand.go:459 error stack: 
    Get https://10.229.0.1:8443/1.0: Gateway Time-out
    github.com/juju/juju/tools/lxdclient/client.go:278: 
    github.com/juju/juju/tools/lxdclient/client.go:132: 
    github.com/juju/juju/provider/lxd/environ_raw.go:92: 
    github.com/juju/juju/provider/lxd/environ.go:67: 
    github.com/juju/juju/provider/lxd/provider.go:57: 
    github.com/juju/juju/environs/bootstrap/prepare.go:160: 
    github.com/juju/juju/environs/bootstrap/prepare.go:99: 
    github.com/juju/juju/cmd/juju/commands/bootstrap.go:450:
```

What can I do to bootstrap JUJU?

UPDATE:

Tried everything suggested in this thread: [Juju 2.0 proxy for bootstrap](https://askubuntu.com/questions/852154/juju-2-0-proxy-for-bootstrap?rq=1)

`--model-defaults` is undefined for juju 2.2.0

`--config` is simply ignored

`sysop@ubuntu01:~$ juju bootstrap lxd --model-defaults=config.yaml
ERROR flag provided but not defined: --model-defaults
sysop@ubuntu01:~$ juju bootstrap lxd --config=config.yaml
ERROR Get https://10.229.0.1:8443/1.0: Gateway Time-out`

I don't know what else to try. Any suggestion?

---

One step ahead.

Setting the core.http_address to the lxdbr0 address and core.proxy_ignore_hosts to the same address the bootstrap process starts and create the lxc controller container but end in error saying:

```
09:30:29 ERROR juju.cmd.juju.commands bootstrap.go:492 unable to contact api server after 1 attempts: unable to connect to API: malformed HTTP response "\x15\x03\x01\x00\x02\x02\x16"
```

Then the process ends cleaning up the created container.

What can I do?

Lxc info says:

```
    sysop@ubuntu01:~$ lxc info
    config:
    core.https_address: 10.229.0.1:9000
    core.https_allowed_credentials: "true"
    core.https_allowed_headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
    core.https_allowed_methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
    core.https_allowed_origin: https://localhost:8000
    core.proxy_http: http://username:password@proxy:8080/
    core.proxy_https: http://username:password@proxy:8080/
    core.proxy_ignore_hosts: 10.229.0.1
```

`config.yaml` contains:

```
    default-series: xenial
    no-proxy: 10.229.0.1
    apt-http-proxy: http://username:password@proxy:8080
    apt-https-proxy: http://username:password@proxy:8080
    apt-ftp-proxy: http://username:password@proxy:8080
    http-proxy: http://username:password@proxy:8080
    https-proxy: http://username:password@proxy:8080
    ftp-proxy: http://username:password@proxy:8080
```

and the bootstrap log is:

```
    sysop@ubuntu01:~$ juju bootstrap localhost --config config.yaml --debug
    09:09:10 INFO  juju.cmd supercommand.go:63 running juju [2.2.0 gc go1.8]
    09:09:10 DEBUG juju.cmd supercommand.go:64   args: []string{"/snap/juju/1956/bin/juju", "bootstrap", "localhost", "--config", "config.yaml", "--debug"}
    09:09:10 DEBUG juju.tools.lxdclient client.go:230 connecting to LXD remote "local": "unix:///var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/unix.socket"
    09:09:10 INFO  juju.tools.lxdclient client.go:284 using LXD API version "1.0"
    09:09:10 INFO  juju.tools.lxdclient client.go:333 LXD "default" profile uses network bridge "lxdbr0"
    09:09:10 INFO  cmd provider.go:179 Resolved LXD host address on bridge lxdbr0: 10.229.0.1:9000
    09:09:10 INFO  cmd cloudcredential.go:51 no credentials found, checking environment
    09:09:10 DEBUG juju.tools.lxdclient client.go:230 connecting to LXD remote "local": "unix:///var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/unix.socket"
    09:09:10 INFO  juju.tools.lxdclient client.go:284 using LXD API version "1.0"
    09:09:10 INFO  juju.tools.lxdclient client.go:333 LXD "default" profile uses network bridge "lxdbr0"
    09:09:10 DEBUG juju.cmd.juju.commands bootstrap.go:803 authenticating with region "" and credential "localhost" (LXD credential "localhost")
    09:09:10 DEBUG juju.cmd.juju.commands bootstrap.go:915 provider attrs: map[]
    09:09:11 INFO  cmd authkeys.go:114 Adding contents of "/home/sysop/.local/share/juju/ssh/juju_id_rsa.pub" to authorized-keys
    09:09:11 INFO  cmd authkeys.go:114 Adding contents of "/home/sysop/.ssh/id_rsa.pub" to authorized-keys
    09:09:11 DEBUG juju.cmd.juju.commands bootstrap.go:971 preparing controller with config: map[logging-config: authorized-keys:ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCpLnUIrvGmeOMKaH0KLltB94Hn20c4ARM6/vSW6PguUr04+EzU2q9s/GFiIq7VjC0aWxQydDJG/4HqThf0VX5nB9h5sYBLIaq8LoMemw/FtsZrnQ2En3u9kngvcYkRmQEcyCzdHmhzVKG1JAE3NYz67aCaa2OAWZw7fDcXP78KsYDuSv8eTFr4qPoGGi2ayG/NeXkM8WgS8fgQI9emOn9zFVrHIo7Ah2Wa9ucUJjXQvNA+6hZjM2DnxeLV4gdVLxLBvxF1Vj9MHqArPBUZ4ZEFGcdXYoPyny2S6iT3vf3fbCaU785JNweCQwZ0oxRXCDYWXPhGY4zVwzUK1ykojOrh juju-client-key
    ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCjq011k7jLFei5RL7m07dDwEHA4hoKI9AN/WlfjH+ThrUErSV4vG3SRL3jClUldirTTLeT3XwwiGMpLAfxtamI/cbFjuqCY7nHJ+zgQ+GfmgpMfulYxJgz9D1oGdL8+Mn3EfG5V4pfDe1uTiOkmKkChh53rWTznAuDQYbFaXlbQdsVbUDRjmhuAjKnPqX/81WKeB4XedNAsycsqhBmK2ITx22ff2PwkHaegsGUzbXcRVY8i47gq96vCU3gLb64fUkTA9miEAovtpalsr13jSbzTrLfwtExVbpew0EAb4de5BqQATqOtexD6CNzkxEzmHp7am0c8MdzMjBFpkCIN29/ sysop@ubuntu01
    max-status-history-age:336h enable-os-upgrade:true test-mode:false firewall-mode:instance image-metadata-url: image-stream:released ftp-proxy:http://username:password@proxy:8080 agent-stream:released name:controller development:false agent-metadata-url: resource-tags: transmit-vendor-metrics:true http-proxy:http://username:password@proxy:8080 max-status-history-size:5G apt-no-proxy: apt-mirror: net-bond-reconfigure-delay:17 apt-http-proxy:http://username:password@proxy:8080 default-series:xenial type:lxd logforward-enabled:false enable-os-refresh-update:true apt-https-proxy:http://username:password@proxy:8080 provisioner-harvest-mode:destroyed uuid:dc69de65-706c-4839-8456-b3afc7dce7f9 proxy-ssh:false automatically-retry-hooks:true ssl-hostname-verification:true no-proxy:10.229.0.1 apt-ftp-proxy:http://username:password@proxy:8080 disable-network-management:false https-proxy:http://username:password@proxy:8080 ignore-machine-addresses:false]
    09:09:11 DEBUG juju.tools.lxdclient client.go:230 connecting to LXD remote "remote": "10.229.0.1:9000"
    09:09:11 INFO  juju.tools.lxdclient client.go:284 using LXD API version "1.0"
    09:09:11 INFO  cmd bootstrap.go:481 Creating Juju controller "localhost-localhost" on localhost/localhost
    09:09:11 INFO  juju.cmd.juju.commands bootstrap.go:536 combined bootstrap constraints: 
    09:09:11 DEBUG juju.environs.bootstrap bootstrap.go:199 model "controller" supports service/machine networks: false
    09:09:11 DEBUG juju.environs.bootstrap bootstrap.go:201 network management by juju enabled: true
    09:09:11 INFO  cmd bootstrap.go:233 Loading image metadata
    09:09:11 INFO  cmd bootstrap.go:296 Looking for packaged Juju agent version 2.2.0 for amd64
    09:09:11 INFO  juju.environs.bootstrap tools.go:72 looking for bootstrap agent binaries: version=2.2.0
    09:09:11 INFO  juju.environs.tools tools.go:101 finding agent binaries in stream "released"
    09:09:11 INFO  juju.environs.tools tools.go:103 reading agent binaries with major.minor version 2.2
    09:09:11 INFO  juju.environs.tools tools.go:111 filtering agent binaries by version: 2.2.0
    09:09:11 INFO  juju.environs.tools tools.go:117 filtering agent binaries by architecture: amd64
    09:09:11 DEBUG juju.environs.tools urls.go:109 trying datasource "keystone catalog"
    09:09:12 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:683 using default candidate for content id "com.ubuntu.juju:released:tools" are {20161007 mirrors:1.0 content-download streams/v1/cpc-mirrors.sjson []}
    09:09:14 INFO  juju.environs.bootstrap tools.go:74 found 15 packaged agent binaries
    09:09:14 INFO  cmd bootstrap.go:357 Starting new instance for initial controller
    09:09:14 INFO  cmd environ.go:152 To configure your system to better support LXD containers, please see: https://github.com/lxc/lxd/blob/master/doc/production-setup.md
    Launching controller instance(s) on localhost/localhost...
    09:09:14 DEBUG juju.provider.lxd environ_broker.go:40 StartInstance: "0", xenial
    09:09:14 DEBUG juju.cloudconfig.instancecfg instancecfg.go:825 Setting numa ctl preference to false
    09:09:14 DEBUG juju.environs imagemetadata.go:112 obtained image datasource "default cloud images"
    09:09:14 DEBUG juju.environs imagemetadata.go:112 obtained image datasource "default ubuntu cloud images"
    09:09:14 DEBUG juju.provider.lxd environ_broker.go:112 LXD requires https://, using: https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/
    09:09:14 DEBUG juju.tools.lxdclient client.go:230 connecting to LXD remote "default cloud images": "https://streams.canonical.com/juju/images/releases/"
    09:09:14 INFO  juju.tools.lxdclient client_image.go:166 no image for juju/xenial/amd64 found in https://streams.canonical.com/juju/images/releases/
    09:09:14 DEBUG juju.tools.lxdclient client.go:230 connecting to LXD remote "default ubuntu cloud images": "https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/"
    09:09:15 INFO  juju.tools.lxdclient client_image.go:170 found image from https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/ for juju/xenial/amd64 = 7a7ff654cbd8f5f09bec03aa19d8d7d92649127d18659036a963b1ea63f90d25
    09:09:17 INFO  juju.tools.lxdclient client_image.go:182 copying image for juju/xenial/amd64 from https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/: metadata: 100% (1.62GB/s)
    09:09:20 INFO  juju.tools.lxdclient client_image.go:182 copying image for juju/xenial/amd64 from https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/: rootfs: 1% (548.63kB/s)
    [...snip...]
    09:15:13 INFO  juju.tools.lxdclient client_image.go:182 copying image for juju/xenial/amd64 from https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/: rootfs: 99% (436.00kB/s)
    09:15:16 INFO  juju.tools.lxdclient client_image.go:182 copying image for juju/xenial/amd64 from https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/: rootfs: 100% (435.60kB/s)
    09:15:19 DEBUG juju.tools.lxdclient client_image.go:174 dropped 0 progress messagess/: rootfs: 100% (435.60kB/s)
    09:15:19 DEBUG juju.service discovery.go:63 discovered init system "systemd" from series "xenial"               
    09:15:19 DEBUG juju.provider.lxd environ_broker.go:230 LXD user data; 3981 bytes
    09:15:19 INFO  juju.provider.lxd environ_broker.go:211 starting instance "juju-dce7f9-0" (image "juju/xenial/amd64")...
    09:16:08 INFO  juju.provider.lxd environ_broker.go:56 started instance "juju-dce7f9-0"                          
    - juju-dce7f9-0 (arch=amd64)          
    09:16:09 INFO  juju.environs.bootstrap bootstrap.go:601 newest version: 2.2.0
    09:16:09 INFO  juju.environs.bootstrap bootstrap.go:616 picked bootstrap agent binary version: 2.2.0
    09:16:09 INFO  juju.environs.bootstrap bootstrap.go:393 Installing Juju agent on bootstrap instance
    09:16:10 INFO  cmd bootstrap.go:480 Fetching Juju GUI 2.7.3
    09:16:10 DEBUG juju.cloudconfig.instancecfg instancecfg.go:825 Setting numa ctl preference to false
    Waiting for address
    Attempting to connect to 10.229.0.159:22
    09:16:36 DEBUG juju.provider.common bootstrap.go:497 connection attempt for 10.229.0.159 failed: /var/lib/juju/nonce.txt does not exist
    09:16:41 INFO  juju.cloudconfig userdatacfg_unix.go:410 Fetching agent: curl -sSfw 'tools from %{url_effective} downloaded: HTTP %{http_code}; time %{time_total}s; size %{size_download} bytes; speed %{speed_download} bytes/s ' --retry 10 -o $bin/tools.tar.gz <[https://streams.canonical.com/juju/tools/agent/2.2.0/juju-2.2.0-ubuntu-amd64.tgz]>
    09:20:29 INFO  cmd bootstrap.go:420 Bootstrap agent now started
    09:20:30 INFO  juju.juju api.go:308 API endpoints changed from [] to [10.229.0.159:17070]
    09:20:31 INFO  cmd controller.go:82 Contacting Juju controller at 10.229.0.159 to verify accessibility...
    09:20:31 INFO  juju.juju api.go:67 connecting to API addresses: [10.229.0.159:17070]
    09:30:29 DEBUG juju.api apiclient.go:806 error dialing websocket: malformed HTTP response "\x15\x03\x01\x00\x02\x02\x16"
    09:30:29 ERROR juju.cmd.juju.commands bootstrap.go:492 unable to contact api server after 1 attempts: unable to connect to API: malformed HTTP response "\x15\x03\x01\x00\x02\x02\x16"
    09:30:29 DEBUG juju.cmd.juju.commands bootstrap.go:493 (error details: [{github.com/juju/juju/cmd/juju/common/controller.go:115: unable to contact api server after 1 attempts} {github.com/juju/juju/cmd/juju/common/controller.go:39: } {github.com/juju/juju/juju/api.go:72: } {github.com/juju/juju/api/apiclient.go:190: } {github.com/juju/juju/api/apiclient.go:596: } {github.com/juju/juju/api/apiclient.go:711: } {github.com/juju/juju/api/apiclient.go:807: unable to connect to API} {github.com/juju/juju/api/apiclient.go:831: } {malformed HTTP response "\x15\x03\x01\x00\x02\x02\x16"}])
    09:30:29 DEBUG juju.cmd.juju.commands bootstrap.go:1078 cleaning up after failed bootstrap
    09:30:29 INFO  juju.provider.common destroy.go:20 destroying model "controller"
    09:30:29 INFO  juju.provider.common destroy.go:31 destroying instances
    09:30:41 INFO  juju.provider.common destroy.go:51 destroying storage
    09:30:41 DEBUG juju.provider.lxd environ.go:193 instances: []
    09:30:41 INFO  cmd supercommand.go:465 command finished
    sysop@ubuntu
```

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the Juju controller for created in LXD (10.229.0.159) isn't being reached directly from the client but instead going through the proxy. Try using `lxc network edit` to decrease the DHCP range to around 10-15 addresses then update `config.yaml` put in a range of IP addresses in for the `no-proxy`.

Proxies have always been trickier than necessary in Juju. I'll open a bug to add something like `proxy-juju-network` flag to the config. If set to `True` then all network traffic to bootstrap and machines launched by Juju will go through the proxy settings, if set to `False` (default) then any address in the Juju model (bootstrap and deployed machines) will automatically be added to the no-proxy list.

Comment: Thanks. It will be useful. For now I'm able to reach the controller container; but I cannot add the proxy settings inside the container (see my delete reply)